# How to programmatically select multiple nodes in RadTreeView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, treeview

I want to programmatically select multiple nodes in my RadTreeView from `Telerik` component in a C# application. *It's a winform*.

I've set `MultiSelect` property to `True`. But when I try this:

```
myTree.SelectedNodes= someNodeCollection;
```

It says:

> SelectedNodes has no setter

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Winforms or Wpf or which UI framework?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it's a winform

Comment: Winforms [TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't even have `SelectedNodes` property. Which `TreeView` you're talking about?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Oh! Sorry! it's a `RadTreeView` from `Telerik` components

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems you can select the individual nodes by setting `node.Selected = true`; I guess that will add the node to `SelectedNodes` collection automatically.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes. Thank you. that did the trick. I couldn't check the documentations, cuz we are in sanctions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a node, you need to set its Selected property:

```
foreach (RadTreeNode node in radTreeView1.Nodes)
{
     node.Selected = true;
}
```